# PHP iconv function - deletes all string after the first unicode character in the string

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, iconv

```
$string = @iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8", $string);
```

I'm using this code to replace Unicode characters in my string, but actually what this does is remove all characters after the first Unicode sign in the string. Is there any other function to helps me to do this?

Comment: You want to remove unicode charactes?

Comment: yes.................

Comment: Your code transform UTF-8 string to an other UTF-8 string... Maybe you need to change the second parameters.

Take a look to the PHP doc : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: @Inazo I read somewhere, that this is a know bug. I try to avoid using this function altogether if there is a better way of doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest doing this with `preg_replace` like this:

```
preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/u', '', $string);
```

or even better:

```
preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F\xA0]/u', '', $string);
```

If the above does not work for your case, this might:

```
preg_replace( '/[^[:cntrl:]]/', '',$string);
```

There is also the option to filter what you need instead of removing what you do not. Something like this should work:

```
filter_var($string, FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW|FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
```

Comment: @doki Well, it really depends on what you have as input. This is why I gave multiple solutions, as I do not know which will be the right one for you. Glad I could help you :)